# Expected number of buckets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have three buckets A, B and C.

Every ball goes into a bucket according to a uniform distribution (same likelihood for every bucket).
Every ball also has a number.
During a time window of ball selections, numbers are unique.
Every new time window reuses the same numbers.

After *n* windows, for any given number *x*, how many buckets will on average contain a ball with number *x* ?

for n == 1, the answer is obviously 1.

Example:

Time window 1: [1,3,2,4] ---> A = {2}, B={3}, C={1,4}

Time window 2: [4,2,3,1] ---> A = {2,3}, B={3,1,4}, C={1,4,2}

Comment: how many balls are there? when you say "at random" do you mean uniformly distributed?

Comment: This is completely unclear. Please give a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ be equal to $1$ if, after $n$ windows, bucket A has at least one ball labelled $x$, and let $X=0$ otherwise. Define $Y$ and $Z$ analogously. Let $W=X+Y+Z$. We want $E(W)$, which is $E(X)+E(Y)+E(Z)$.

The probability that $X=0$ is $(2/3)^n$, so $E(X)=\Pr(X=1)=1-(2/3)^n$. By symmetry $E(Y)=E(Z)=E(X)$. Thus $E(W)=3\left(1-(2/3)^n\right)$.

Comment: The probability that X=0 is  (2/3)^n. I don't fully understand this.

Comment: @PaulPraet: We have $X=0$ if $n$ times in a row ball $x$ has missed A. The probability of missing A in any one trial is $2/3$, so the probability of missing it $n$ times in a row is $(2/3)^n$.